# VB.NET: How to make a webRequest async

Tags: vb.net

I think this is a simple question for you, but I don't understand other cases of webRequests, so I asked here:

How can I make this webRequest asynchronous?

```
Dim sBuffer As String
Dim oRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
oRequest.Method = "GET"
Dim oResponse As WebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse()
Dim oStream As New StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream())
sBuffer = oStream.ReadToEnd()
oStream.Close()
oResponse.Close()
Return sBuffer
```

Thank you for your help!

Regards, Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a function with a simple return value cannot be sinmply made asynchronous, you need to find another method of handling the data that comes back. I would suggest using System.Net.WebClient which is a much easier wrapper on what you've done above, with this class asynch is really easy.

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf DownloadCompletedHander
wc.DownloadStringAsync(url)
```

...

```
Public Shared Sub DownloadCompletedHander(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = False AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
        Dim myString As String = CStr(e.Result)
        'Do stuff with data
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't really speak VB.net but i think thats right from some googling

Comment: how could you put the POST and its parameter using that ?